# SocketRocket (iOS) : How to identify whom user are chatting with another?

Tags: python, ios, objective-c, xcode, socketrocket

I would like to create multiple sockets between all users. 
So how can i pass key and ID such as the server is divided in seprated windows.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do exactly that: you [can] pass around keys and make them show up in separate windows.

From the way you've phrased your question, you appear new to streams/sockets. I'd recommend you first start with one socket and make a chat application so you can get a feel for how to develop protocols which let you do that.

Comment: I do begin the socket with chat application, but now no have any idea about pass the user id and response on the user id. if u know, tell me. using SocketRocket.

Comment: Just make up identifiers and, once you open the socket, send the identifier.

Comment: Every time you send a message, send your ID also... That way every message has the sender's ID...

Comment: Thank you sir for replying, but i am not identify the correct way of send data, i think data send into the dictionary????